# Skyrim Warriors Killing Me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm inside the 'Sleeping Giant Inn' and some warriors keep comming in and saying 'We are going to teach you a lesson' and then they kill me. I dont know why, I have not kiled anyone. If I go outside they are there. What do I do to make them go away.

P.S. I have stolen a few things from the inn before but I dont see how that would affect the warriors.

Comment: Have you tried talking to them or paying your bounty? (Stealing will result in a bounty put on you, and in turn - Warriors; guards would come chasing after you)

Comment: If they're saying "We're here to teach you a lesson," they're probably hired thugs, not guards.

Answer (score 5):

This is known as the Hired Thugs encounter, and is triggered by stealing from or killing an NPC, *whether or not you were seen doing so.* One of the thugs will be carrying a contract naming you as the recipient of their "lessons".

Really, the only way to deal with them is to fight; the guards may offer some assistance if you run outside, and if you keep running, the thugs won't follow you into another city or a dungeon, but it's not easy to avoid combat.

I think this encounter mainly exists to ensure that crime doesn't *always* pay - in Morrowind, and to a lesser extend Oblivion, it became quite easy to commit a wild burglary spree with minimal conflicts or consequences. In Skyrim, you get beat up, even if you're super-sneaky.

(Source: [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hired_Thug))

Comment: And not just for murder and theft. "This is only supposed to occur after the Dragonborn has stolen goods from a character, repeatedly trespassed, assaulted someone, or murdered someone. Some characters, such as Belethor, may consider knocking over items or using a shout inside their shop as reason enough." (Source: [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hired_Thug))